# Table width in flex item

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox

I have trouble with width size of a table inside a flex-item.
I want the flex item parent **fit** the table width (table-layout property must stay auto).

I do not have the same result on IE11 (KO) and chrome (OK).

Minimal reproduction : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OjweJw?editors=1100.

```css
.wrapper{
  background-color:PALEGREEN;
  display:flex;
  padding: 15px 15px 0 15px;
  font-size:20px;
}

.div1{
  background-color:LIGHTCORAL;
  flex-grow:0;
  flex-shrink:0;
  flex-basis:300px;
  max-width:300px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.div2{
  background-color:LIGHTBLUE;
  flex-grow:1;
  flex-shrink:1;
  flex-basis:0px;
}
.div2 p{
    border:10px solid black;
}

table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="div1">
    <p>sidebarrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr</p>
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    <p>tableau header</p>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Titre 1</th>
        <th>Titre 2</th>
        <th>Titre 3</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cellule A1jhkfdsahjfdslkjhfdsalkjhfdsalkjhfdsakjhfdsakjhfdsakjhfdsakjhfdsakjhfdsakjhfdsakjhfdsakjhfdsakjhfdsakjhfdsakjhfdsakjhfdsakjhfdsakjhfdsakjhfdsakjhfdsakjhfdsakjhfdsalkjhlkjhfdsalkjhfdsalkjhfdsakjfdsakjhfdsalkjhfdsalkjh</td>
        <td>Cellule A2</td>
        <td>Cellule A3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cellule B1</td>
        <td>Cellule B2kjfdsakjfdyslkjfdsalkfdsalkjfdsalkjfdsalkjfdsalkjfdsalkjfdsalkjfdsalkj</td>
        <td>Cellule B3</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

How make it works on IE too ?

Thanks,

Autofocus.